# Removing Numbers and Errant Letters from string

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to parse some information down (with **VBA**, in Excel), removing numbers and "associated letters".  Unfortunately, there's not much of a straightforward pattern I can think of so far as programming goes.  However, "looking at it", I can see where I'd want to cut the data off.

Here's a mock list of info (each line is a single cell):

```
Maersk Bentonville voy. 1283
CRC Brooklyn 183E
Piraeus 298ER20
Seago Istanbul - voy. 182
Maersk Bulan YH828
Buton 164NN
Seago Bremerhaven One
Seago Antwerp 149E
Captain Maersk NY8821
Carsten Maersk OC9192
Cecilie Vessel 12N3R
Charlotte Maersk 1290
```

Desired Output:

```
Maersk Bentonville
CRC Brooklyn
Piraeus
Seago Istanbul
Maersk Bulan
Buton
Seago Bremerhaven One
Seago Antwerp
Captain Maersk
Carsten Maersk
Cecilie Vessel
Charlotte Maersk
```

I'm just trying to get the name (i.e. `Maersk Bentonville`).  There's not a master list I have anywhere to compare to, so I just want to remove "voy." and the number/letter group, i.e. `183E`, `298ER20`, etc.

I'm able to get pretty close with the below function:

```
Function RemoveNumbers(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9]|[-+./]+|(voy)"
    RemoveNumbers = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

But you'll notice it leaves me with `Maersk Brooklyn E`, `Maersk Bulan YH`.

I suppose my question is: Is there a way to see if that group with numbers has letters in it? And if so, just remove that group?

I'm sure there's a regex pattern, but I'm still learning regex so haven't figured it out, but would love to find one.

If there are any other options, I'm open to that too.  Of course, I can loop through each character in the cell, and note when a number appears next to a letter, then start tracking until the next space, then remove that group, but that seems pretty inefficient.

Thanks for any ideas, let me know if I can clarify anything!

PS: I can't just "cut" the last group of text. Sometimes I have a cell with three names I want to keep (`Seago Bremerhaven One`), and sometimes I just have two parts `Maersk Ship`, `Seago Antwerp`, or `Seago 29E2R`.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the desired **output**

Comment: @PedroLobito - added, sorry!

Comment: @YowE3K - I knew I needed to add it, just didn't want to add another block of text to the question, so I just gave the one example. But yeah, I know :(

Comment: @BruceWayne NP, it happens. I think Rahul has your answer. GL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the anchor `^` at beginning of string you can extract names.

**Regex:** `^(?:[A-Za-z]+\s)*` with multi-line option ON

**Explanation:**

`^` will start matching at beginning of line.
`(?:[A-Za-z]+\s)*` will look for combination of characters (assuming names don't have numbers in it) followed by a whitespace. This pattern will be search for multiple times since `*` quantifier is used. Thus matching more than one name in a line.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/km6kY9/2/)**

Comment: Ooh - Close! With an input of `Maersk Captain 1235N`, this returns `1235N`. How do I get the *reverse* of that, `Maersk Captain`?

Comment: @BruceWayne: As per your expected output `Maersk Captain` is matching. _How do I get the reverse of that, Maersk Captain?_ I don't understand your question.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Ohk ! I get it now. You wish to wipe out trailing data other than name ! I wrote regex for matching names. Well try if you can match. I am no good in VBA.

Comment: With some slight tweaking in VBA, I was able to get this to work.  For posterity: The regex you gave will successfully grab the part I want to *remove* from the string.  (`Maersk Ship 0012E` becomes `0012E`. I want `Maersk Ship` only).  So to remedy this, I simply used Excel's `SUBSTITUTE()` function to replace the regex found string with `""`.  I'm going to keep playing with this to see if I can get the "reverse" to work, but thanks a zillion for your help! :D

Comment: @BruceWayne: Glad to be of help to ╭^-^╮.

Comment: Jute to note, in the case where there's no number/letter group, the pattern will remove the second word.  For example, `Maersk Ship` becomes `Maersk`. I need it to remain `Maersk Ship`.  I'm avoiding that via VBA (basically `If string doesn't have numbers in it, return original input`) though as a workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142863/discussion-between-rahul-and-brucewayne).